# Equality of Trace Maximisation

Tags: optimization, trace

Given two optimization problems:

1. $ \underset{X}{max} \quad tr(X^T B X A) $
2. $ \underset{X}{max} \quad tr(X^T B^2 X A^2) $

where A,B are both symmetrisch positive definite. How can I show, that both optimizations are the same?

Comment: What constraints are there on $X$? If there are no constraints then neither of these optimizations are bounded, for any choice of $A,B$.

Comment: To see this just take $X= \alpha I$ for some $\alpha > 0$. Both objective functions increase with $\alpha$.